# Using a macro to sort data from instrumentation software

Tags: vba, excel

So I use an instrumentation software at work that outputs readings to a csv excel file. Because of the length of the test and the readings every 30 seconds, I accumulate a few thousand  rows for every 24 hours of the test. When the test runs, it reads things that I don't need readings of so I have to go through the sheet manually and replace the "false" readings with zeros.

What I would like to do is use a command button to prompt the user to select a column to sort and apply a range of values so if it falls within that range, it returns the value to the cell and if it doesn't fall within the range, it returns a 0. I have done this with smaller sheets with extra columns (see attached file) but I'm not super familiar with Macros or VBA so I'm not sure where to get started.

Can anyone give me a hand?

[image: Example of what I do now]

Comment: By `Sorted` do you mean `Corrected`?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as follows.

1) Go to Developer tab in the Excel ribbon. Click Insert, choose a Command Button (ActiveX Control) and place it onto the sheet where you want to have it.

2) Double-click the button, this will open up the editor. You should see:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

End Sub
```

3) Add the line `UserForm1.Show` inside of this block of code. This should now look like:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

4) Now we will create the userform. On the left side of the editor you will see a section called "Projects - VBA Project", in this list you should see your Workbook. Right click the name of your workbook and click Insert -> UserForm.

5) Use the toolbox to drag the correct components into the Userform. You are free to customize this form as you see fit to add or remove functionality based on your needs. I made mine look like this: [image]

6) In the projects tab you will see your userform named UserForm1. Right click this userform and click "View Code". Paste the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Unload UserForm1
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

   Dim lastColumn As Long
   lastColumn = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   For i = 1 To lastColumn
      UserForm1.ComboBox1.AddItem (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, i))
   Next
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

  Dim columnName As String
  Dim columnIndex As Integer
  Dim min As Double
  Dim max As Double

  If Not (ComboBox1.SelText = "" And TextBox1.Text = "" And TextBox2.Text = "") Then

    columnName = ComboBox1.SelText

    min = TextBox1.Text
    max = TextBox2.Text

    Dim lastColumn As Long
    lastColumn = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = 1 To lastColumn
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, i).Value = columnName Then
            columnIndex = i
        End If
    Next

    Dim cellValue As Double

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        cellValue = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, columnIndex).Value

        ' MsgBox CStr(cellValue) + "--" + CStr(cellValue > min) + "--" + CStr(cellValue < max)

        If Not (cellValue >= min And cellValue <= max) Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, columnIndex).Value = 0
        End If
    Next

   End If

   Unload UserForm1

End Sub
```

7) Change the component names such as CommandButton, ComboBox1, etc. to match your UserForm.

**What does the code do?**

Initializing: As soon as the UserForm is called it passes through the method `UserForm_Initialize()`. This method looks through your WorkSheet and determines the name of all the columns. It then adds these to the ComboBox.

Command Button 1: "Cancel", exits the UserForm without doing anything.

Command Button 2: "Confirm", this method goes to your selected column, checks within the desired range. If a value falls outside that range then it will set it to 0.

I hope this help!!